# Comparar duas querys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, linq

Tenho uma query que devolve só os catequizandos que foram ao evento:

```
 var catequizandosCheked = (from cat in db.Catequizando
                                       where cat.Eventos.Any(e => e.EventoID == eventoID)
                                       select new PresencaEventoViewModel
                                       {
                                           CatequizandoID = cat.CatequizandoID                                          
                                       }).ToList();
```

e tenho outra query que devolve todos os catequizados:

```
 var catequizandos = (from i in db.Inscricao
                                 join c in db.Catequizando on i.CatequizandoID equals c.CatequizandoID
                                 join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
                                 join g in db.Grupo on i.GrupoID equals g.GrupoID
                                 where queryAnoPastoral.Contains(i.AnoPastoral)
                                 select new PresencaEventoViewModel
                                 {
                                     Nome = p.Nome,
                                     CatequizandoID = p.PessoaID,
                                     AnoCatequese = i.AnoCatequese,
                                     LetraGrupo = g.LetraGrupo,
                                     Estado = !catequizandosCheked.Contains(p.PessoaID) ? "unchecked" : (catequizandosCheked.Contains(p.PessoaID) ? "checked" : null )                                                                                                                                        
                                 });
```

Na query `catequizandos`pretendo retornar o atributo `Estado` "cheked" ou "Uncheked" se for encontrado ou não, o valor do catequizandoID  na query `catequizandos`

Comment: Qual o problema? Alguma das _queries_ não está funcionando? O atributo `Estado` não está retornando certo?

Comment: O atributo Estado não está a ser retornado.

Comment: Já tentou _debuggar_ a linha dele e ver se não está sempre caindo no segundo _else_ e recebendo nulo? `Estado = !catequizandosCheked.Contains(p.PessoaID) ? "unchecked" : (catequizandosCheked.Contains(p.PessoaID) ? "checked" : null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução que obtive:

```
Estado = !catequizandosCheked.Contains(p.PessoaID) ? "unchecked" : "checked"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tenta substituir a linha abaixo colocando o exists em vez do containts:

```
!catequizandosCheked.Exists(x => x.CatequizandoID  == p.PessoaID) ? "unchecked" : "checked"
```

Comment: N é reconhecido o metodo Exists em Linq  : 

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Exists(System.Predicate`1[WebAppCatechesis2.ViewModels.PresencaEventoViewModel])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @WickedOne, Não vi que você estava usando operação direta do banco, neste caso tente usar o left join da maneira abaixo:            
`var catequizandos = (from i in db.Inscricao
join _A in catequizandosCheked on p.CatequizandoID equals _A.CatequizandoID into _a
from _A in _a.DefaultIfEmpty()
where queryAnoPastoral.Contains(i.AnoPastoral)
select new PresencaEventoViewModel
{  Estado = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_A.CatequizandoID) ? "unchecked" : "checked"
});`

Answer (score 0):

@WickedOne,
Quando você chama o método [`ToList<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) de um [`IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.100).aspx), você enumera os dados e fala para o `LINQ` que você quer executar a consulta no banco de dados.

Nesse caso, se for `SQL Server`, você diz ao `Provider` que quer que a sua `Query Expression` seja transformada em um script `SQL` no exato momento da execução. Sendo assim, a variável `catequizandosCheked` é do tipo List` e está guardada em memória.

Quando você tenta misturar [Lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) com dados locais, o LINQ/Provider não consegue fazer a tradução do seu `LINQ` para um script `SQL` e por isso dá um erro (imagino que seja esse o seu caso).

Para não "encher muita linguiça" você precisa apenas alterar sua `Query Expression` para:

```
var catequizandosCheked = (from cat in db.Catequizando
                           where cat.Eventos.Any(e => e.EventoID == eventoID)
                           select new PresencaEventoViewModel
                           {
                               CatequizandoID = cat.CatequizandoID                                          
                           });
```

Nesse caso, sem o [`ToList<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx), a variável `catequizandosCheked` passa a ser do tipo `IQueryable<PresencaEventViewModel>` e ainda pode ser traduzida para um script `SQL` e ser usada na outra `Query Expression`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim da-me erro, mas ao retirar o `ToList()` obtenho erro tambem na condição do atributo `Estado` : 'IQueryable<PresencaEventoViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains<int>(ParallelQuery<int>, int)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<int>'

Comment: Por se tratar de um dado numérico, você ainda pode refazer sua query. Alterando o `!catequizandosCheked.Contains(p.PessoaID)` para `!catequizandosCheked.Any(x => p.PessoaID == x.PessoaID)`